# Knockout.js visible binding not working using a function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a function that checks whether a value is a number or not, returning `true` if the value is a number and `false` if not.

#### Javascript

```
function isNumber(value) {
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
        console.log(value + ' is a number')
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log(value + ' is NaN')
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Markup

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: budget">
<span data-bind="visible: isNumber(budget)">Content</span>
```

When the value of `budget` updates I see the correct console logs as expected but the visible binding isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

It is not stated explicitly in your question but I guess that `budget` is an observable;

```
this.budget = ko.observable()
```

Then `budget` in terms of javascript is not a number but a function. That is why `visible` binding does not show your element. You may want to review the documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

In your case you have to use either :

- Values of budget observable in your binding

  ```
  <span data-bind="visible: isNumber(budget())">Content</span>
  ```
- Computed observable in your view model which would still be using `budget()`
  http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/18868/
  This approach is typically considered superior because of better logic/view separation.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I pass `budget` as a function.

```
<span data-bind="visible: isNumber(budget())">Content</span>
```